# Include multiple layouts programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llFunction1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="6dp" />
```

another 2 `RelativeLayouts` like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlCatering"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/linksbtn_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/linksbtn_height"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:background="?attr/selector_button_common" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCatering"
        style="@style/tvLinks"
        android:text="@string/landing_home_lists_catering" />

</RelativeLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rldd"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/linksbtn_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/linksbtn_height"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:background="?attr/selector_button_common" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvdd"
        style="@style/tvLinks"
        android:text="@string/landing_home_lists_dd" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now trying to include these 2 `RelativeLayouts` in first `LinearLayout` using following method:

```
llFunction1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llFunction1);
rlCatering = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.inc_layout_tabcontent_links_catering, null);
llFunction1.addView(rlCatering);
rlDD = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.inc_layout_tabcontent_links_dd, null);
llFunction1.addView(rlDD);
```

But it's including only the first one. If I include directly in the XML it's working fine. Only problem when I am adding programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

Add this into your LinearLayout, it will include the layout **name**  into your LinearLayout.

```
<include layout="@layout/*name*/>
```

Comment: I know this but my question in adding programmatically not directly in XML.

Comment: Yeah I know but it is more simply including layouts in this way.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I need to implement some conditions to add these layouts. So it's forcing me to do programmatically.

Comment: This was not what @ray asked for.